# Get WordPress data object

Tags: wordpress

From a generic WordPress template (currently looking at blankslate, but they seem to have similar information across the board) how would I get all of a page's data?

Does WordPress even have a data object format available from individual pages? I've seen the `$wpdb` object for getting data directly from the database. Would this data object already be available in, for instance, the "page.php" file for that particular page? I'm looking for class/title/content/etc., already in one object.

I'm fairly new to WordPress...

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the `get_post()` function provides this functionality. I'd still appreciate a more authoritative answer if someone knows a better way.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post